# powershell downloading xml from url - added unix timestamp to url

Tags: xml, powershell, download, timestamp

I have simple powershell skript for downloading XML from url.

I need dynamically added unix timestamp to url, with actual date - in unix timestamp format. then i need running it with windows task scheduler.

code for powershell skript now:

```
 [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://xxxxx&from_date=1668069585" -OutFile "C:\IMPORT\xxx_$(get-date -Format yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm_ss).xml"
```

how can i add unix timestamp after &from_date?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PowerShell v5.1 and above, you can use the **`[datetimeoffset]` type's [`.ToUnixTimeSeconds()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeSeconds) method**:

```bash
$uri = 'https://xxxxx&from_date=' + [datetimeoffset]::Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds()
```

Note:

- PowerShell itself offers **[`Get-Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date) `-UFormat %s`**, which returns the Unix timestamp *as a string*, but this **only works properly in [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)** (in Windows PowerShell, the timestamp is mistakenly expressed in the number of seconds since midnight 1 Jan 1970 *local* time; also, it unexpectedly has a fractional component).

---

**Using a timestamp other than now:**

Like [`[datetime]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime), the unambiguous and more flexible [`[datetimeoffset]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTimeOffset) has various `.Add...()` methods that allow you to calculate the desired timestamp *relative to* another one; e.g., [`.AddDays()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTimeOffset.AddDays):

```bash
# Get *yesterday's* Unix time, at the *same time of day*.
[datetimeoffset]::Now.AddDays(-1).ToUnixTimeSeconds()
```

If you want to use the *start of the day* (midnight) of a given day, e.g. yesterday's:

```bash
# Get the previous *local calendar day's* Unix time, i.e.
# from the start of that day (midnight)
([datetimeoffset] [datetime]::Now.Date).AddDays(-1).ToUnixTimeSeconds()
```

- Note that while `[datetimeoffset]` instances, like those of `[datetime]`, have a `.Date` property that returns a date without a time-of-day-component, that date is (a) a `[datetime]` instance and (b) *ambiguous*, because its `.Kind` property value is *always* `Unspecified`.

More generally, given an arbitrary `[datetimeoffset]` instance, you can eliminate the time-of-day component by subtracting the value of the [`.TimeOfDay`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTimeOffset.TimeOfDay) property, which is relative to whatever UTC offset (time zone) the timestamp is expressed in; e.g., the following is equivalent to the above:

```bash
(($dto = [datetimeoffset]::Now) - $dto.TimeOfDay).AddDays(-1).ToUnixTimeSeconds()
```

Comment: hello, and if i need yesterday time, how can add it? Now-1.ToUnixTimeSeconds?

Comment: how can i test it which unix number return me? becasue i think it not working. i have set it like this: $uri = url adress, and then Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$uri+ ([datetimeoffset] [datetime]::Now.Date).AddDays(-1).ToUnixTimeSeconds()"

Comment: @MartinJašek, you need to enclose expressions that you want to pass as arguments in `(...)`: `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($uri + ([datetimeoffset] [datetime]::Now.Date).AddDays(-1).ToUnixTimeSeconds())`